# Multithread method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a few threads running that do the same task over and over. In that task it has to reauthenticate with a service to get a new sessionkey. But what happens is that all the threads try to reauthenticate.

I want to make it so that the first thread reauthenticating goes through and the others wait for that to complete and then continue as usual.

This is my original test code before implementing a solution:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        AuthManager authClass = new AuthManager();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Thread thr = new Thread(() -> {
                int count = 0;

                while(count < 2) { // Bad practice but just for the example.
                    if(count == 1){
                        if(authClass.reAuthenticate()) {
                            System.out.println("Reauthenticated.");

                            authClass.doStuff();
                        }
                    } else {
                        authClass.doStuff();
                    }

                    count++;
                }
            });

            thr.start();
        }

        // Keep the program running for 30 seconds.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ignored
        }
    }

    private class AuthManager {

        public boolean reAuthenticate(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignored
            }

            System.out.println("Reauthenticating..");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignored
            }

            return true; // or false when no success in the real application.
        }

        public void doStuff(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignored
            }

            System.out.println("Doing stuff.");
        }

    }
}
```

Response:

```
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Reauthenticating..
Reauthenticating..
Reauthenticating..
Reauthenticating..
Reauthenticating..
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
```

The response I want:

```
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Reauthenticating..
Reauthenticated.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
```

How can I achieve this?

**Edit**
I made this now with the response of @haifzhan but this won't work when I have to authenticate again later.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        AuthManager authClass = new AuthManager();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Thread thr = new Thread(() -> {
                int count = 0;

                while(count < 4) { // Bad practice but just for the example.
                    if(count == 1 || count == 3){
                        if(authClass.reAuthenticate()) {
                            System.out.println("Reauthenticated.");

                            authClass.doStuff();
                        }
                    } else {
                        authClass.doStuff();
                    }

                    count++;
                }
            });

            thr.start();
        }

        // Keep the program running for 30 seconds.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ignored
        }
    }

    private class AuthManager {

        private final AtomicBoolean isAuthorized = new AtomicBoolean();

        public synchronized boolean reAuthenticate() {
            if(!isAuthorized.get()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ignored
                }

                System.out.println("Reauthenticating..");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ignored
                }

                isAuthorized.set(true);
                return isAuthorized.get();
            }

            return isAuthorized.get();
        }

        public void doStuff(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignored
            }

            System.out.println("Doing stuff.");
        }

    }
}
```

Response:

```
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Reauthenticating..
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Reauthenticated.
Doing stuff.
Reauthenticated.
Doing stuff.
Reauthenticated.
Doing stuff.
Reauthenticated.
Doing stuff.
Reauthenticated.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
```

The response I want:

```
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Reauthenticating..
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Reauthenticating..
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Reauthenticated.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
Doing stuff.
```

Comment: You made 5 threads that do the same thing (reauthenticate and do stuff) you should try to make only one thread that authenticate and the others that only do stuff or try to check if a thread has already authenticated and in that case skip the reauthenticate stuff.

Comment: @aleb2000 has a good point but in case you are stubborn there are various ways to reduce access to a resource such as - [Semaphores](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).  Just remember it adds to the complexity.

Comment: I didn't know about Semaphores, yea used in the right way it whould work.@zec

Comment: Maybe a synchronized block surrounding the authentication logic?

Comment: How do you know when to re-authenticate? For example, do you have to re-authenticate after a certain number of requests have completed, after a certain time, in response to an error, or what?

Comment: @erickson in response to a specific response saying that the session is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a potential solution:

```
            Thread thr = new Thread(() -> {
                int count = 0;

                while(count < 2) { // Bad practice but just for the example.
                    if (count == 1 && authClass.reAuthenticate()) {
                        System.out.println("Reauthenticated.");

                        authClass.doStuff();
                    } else {
                        authClass.doStuff();
                    }

                    count++;
                }
            });
```

In the first code snippet, I modified a little bit the logic to call `auth.doStuff()` in case `reAuthenticate` returns `false`.

```
    private class AuthManager {

        private volatile boolean reAuthenticate;
        public boolean reAuthenticate(){
            if (!reAuthenticate) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (!reAuthenticate) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // ignored
                        }

                        System.out.println("Reauthenticating..");

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // ignored
                        }
                        return this.reAuthenticate = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

In the second code snippet, I rely on a volatile variable to be able to do a double checking of the value `reAuthenticate` in order to call it only once and not having to acquire any lock for later calls to `reAuthenticate`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Is this better now?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I understand that you can down vote if the answer is not as expected but you should also give the points back when the answer is done as requested, please don't forget that we spend time for free to help people

Comment: Please allow me time away from my computer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you very much for your understanding and your remark

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using your code with a few edits to work for future reauthentications.

Comment: Good news, I'm always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `synchronized` method to change `AtomicBoolean` `isAuthorized`, this makes sure thread-safe, and other thread will not reauthenticating again.

Secondly, you have to improve your rule that how you really want to authenticate, and how to display authenticated and display `doStuff`.  In your while loop, no matter it satisfy if condition or else condition, both print doStuff, you need to find your way to distinguish the result.

```
public synchronized boolean reAuthenticate(){
    if(! isAuthorized.get()){
        System.out.println("Reauthenticating..");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ignored
        }
        isAuthorized.set(true);
        return isAuthorized.get();
    }

    return isAuthorized.get(); // or false when no success in the real application.
}
```

Output:

```
 else doStuff
    else doStuff
    else doStuff
    else doStuff
    else doStuff
    Doing stuff
    Reauthenticating..
    Doing stuff
    Doing stuff
    Doing stuff
    Doing stuff
    Reauthenticated.
    Reauthenticated.
    Reauthenticated.
    Reauthenticated.
    Reauthenticated.
    Doing stuff
    Doing stuff
    Doing stuff
    Doing stuff
    Doing stuff
```

`Reauthenticated` printed multiple times because your code print this line out once `reAuthenticate()` is true.

Comment: Thanks for that, I am now half-way there. I have edited the original question, could you take a look at that?

Comment: Why are you using `AtomicBoolean` inside a block that is already atomic? Do you intend for `isAuthorized` to be accessed in other methods too?

Comment: @erickson youre right.  i edited with my first post with `synchronized` and leave the rest untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [read-write lock.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)

Threads can "do stuff," when they acquire the read lock, but must acquire the write lock in order to re-authenticate.

Using a read-write lock will prevent any threads from "doing stuff" during the time that another thread is re-authenticating, but won't otherwise interfere. This will minimize the number of requests that fail because of authorization, because as soon as one thread notices that re-authentication is necessary, it will request the write lock, and no other threads will be able to acquire the read lock (and fail because re-authentication is pending).

Comment: Can I make the other wait and use the same response as the one that acquired the lock when its finished with this?

Comment: Yes. Essentially, the lock will guard access to the session identifier. All threads can acquire the lock and read the session identifier, but when it's found to be invalid, one thread will acquire the write lock, and exclude others from reading it until it's updated.